# Why store oauth 1.0 token's in a database - why not just keep in session?

Tags: oauth

Not quite sure why it is 'recommended' to store token's in database - I can just store in session.

Comment: Can you add a link to this recommendation?

Comment: The class I'm using has this recommendation in the documentation, http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION (point 7) ... I've also read it on another site somewhere, so I thought it was standard practice.

Answer (score 1):

well, I guess storing the token in `DB` is the best way to use an application (based on Oauth),

'cause,  when a user try to use an app he need to give access/authorize  to  his account, If you're storing the tokens in a session, if the session expires, the user again need to authorize his account which is very annoying. when you store the users identity in database,  user doesn't need to authorize his account anymore, So Storing the Tokens is makes user comfort with the specific app xD

Comment: But presumably you would use the session to maintain the state of the user (their twitter ID for example), so if the session expires you have no way of linking back to the token and would have to authorize again anyway. What am I missing?